# How to pass a scriptBlock into a class method?

Tags: powershell

In powershell, lets say I have a scriptblock:

```
$myscript = {
    write-host "hello!"
    write-host "good-bye!"
}
```

And I want to have a method in a powershell class that takes a script block as a parameter, how would you do that?  example:

```
class myclass {
    myclass() {}

    method1([ScriptBlockType]$script) {
         Invoke-Command -Computer comp1 -ScriptBlock $script
    }
}

$c = [myclass]::new($myscript)
$c.method1($myscript)
```

What type of object is a ScriptBlock?

Comment: you can write `[scriptblock]` and that's shorthand for [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.scriptblock?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0) type.

Comment: In the future, you can find out by yourself, e. g. `$myscript.GetType().Name`.